# How to find difference of array items in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find difference of two array items. For example I am expecting `[-1, -4], [-2, 4], [1, -2]` from `[arr[i],arr[i+1]].transpose.map{|x| x.reduce(:-)}`. But I get an error, `transpose': no implicit conversion of nil into Array (TypeError).

```
myarr =[]
i=0
arr = [[1,1],[2,5],[4,1],[3,3]]
while i < arr.length
  myarr = [arr[i],arr[i+1]].transpose.map{|x| x.reduce(:-)}.dosomething
  i += 1
end

def dosomething
...
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?
New to Ruby.

Comment: Your loop runs to `i == arr.length-1`, but inside you do `arr[i+1]` so that will be `nil` since that index is out of bounds.

Comment: `[].dosomething` will cause another *undefined method* error. You can either define `module Enumerable; def dosomething() …; end; end` (bad idea for single purpose methods) or call `dosomething` with the result of map: `dosomething [].transpose.map{…}` (this will need a parameter for `dosomething`, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
arr = [[1,1],[2,5],[4,1],[3,3]]

def dosomething(myarr)
  puts myarr.to_s
end

arr.each_cons(2) do |pairs|
  myarr = pairs.transpose.map{|x| x.reduce(:-)}
  dosomething(myarr)
end
# [-1, -4]
# [-2, 4]
# [1, -2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to calculate the argument for `do_something` is to make use of Ruby's [Matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class and [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
require 'matrix'

arr = [[1,1],[2,5],[4,1],[3,3]]

diff = arr[0..-2].zip(arr.drop(1)).map { |a,b| (Matrix[a] - Matrix[b]).to_a }
  #=> [[[-1, -4]], [[-2, 4]], [[1, -2]]]
```